# How to find two unsigned char in QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I'm pretty new to C ++ and Qt. I'm trying to check if a QByteArray shows two consecutive times a certain unsigned char. Unfortunately I am not able to make it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
QByteArray byteArray;
unsigned char start_stop = 0xFE;


if(byteArray.contains(start_stop))
{
//this one is working
}


if(byteArray.contains(start_stop+start_stop))
{
//This one not
}


if(byteArray.contains(start_stop, start_stop))
{
//This one not
}
```

Comment: What do you think `start_stop + start_stop` will do?
Hint: your code equals `unsigned char x = start_stop + start_stop; if(byteArray.contains(x)) ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, start_stop + start_stop is not what I want. It is not the same as 2x the element in a row

Comment: Correctly, because it adds `start_stop` to `start_stop` and then searches for the result of this addition. You should take a look at [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) and you will find the function you need. `count` and `indexOf` look promising.

Comment: please add to the question how are you testing that, input , desired output and actual output...

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange a function like this:

```
bool containsStartStop(const QByteArray & byteArray)
{
    return byteArray.contains(QByteArray(2, static_cast<char>(0xFE)));
}
```

or this:

```
bool containsStartStop(const QByteArray & byteArray)
{
    return QString(byteArray.toHex()).contains("FEFE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, find the index of the first occurrence of two consecutive stop characters in a byte array:

```
#include <QtCore/QByteArray>    
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char stop{'b'};
  const QByteArray v{"abcdebbaacdea"};
  std::cout << v.indexOf(QByteArray(2, stop)) << '\n'; // outputs: 5
}
```